# SQL Server UNION inside a PIVOT not working

Tags: sql-server, pivot, union

I am trying to make the following query work in SQL Server 2008. An error message simply stating "Incorrect syntax near PivotTable" (which is the very end) is returned. Can anyone help me with finding the error?

```
SELECT * FROM (
 (SELECT p_id, [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents_secureworks].[classification],
  DATENAME(mm, occurrence) as [month]
  FROM [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents_secureworks]
  WHERE [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents_secureworks].[type] = 'Security Incident'
  AND occurrence >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,-12,getdate())), 0)
  AND occurrence < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,0,getdate())), 0)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT p_id, [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents].[classification],
   DATENAME(mm, occurrence) as [month]
   FROM [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents]
   WHERE (occurrence >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,-12,getdate())), 0)
   AND occurrence < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,0,getdate())), 0)))
 AS SourceTable

PIVOT (
 COUNT(p_id)
 FOR [month] in ([August],[September],[October],[November],[December],[January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ( (` has two open brackets.

Comment: Formatting your code would be helpful to finding these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i always say formatting may show the problem...

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
            SELECT  p_id, 
                    [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents_secureworks].[classification],
                    DATENAME(mm, occurrence) as [month]
            FROM    [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents_secureworks]
            WHERE   [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents_secureworks].[type] = 'Security Incident'
                    AND occurrence >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,-12,getdate())), 0)
                    AND occurrence < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,0,getdate())), 0)
            UNION   ALL
            SELECT  p_id, 
                    [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents].[classification],
                    DATENAME(mm, occurrence) as [month]
            FROM    [InfoSec].[dbo].[tb_incidents]
            WHERE   (
                        occurrence >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,-12,getdate())), 0)
                        AND occurrence < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,0,getdate())), 0))
                    )
        ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT(p_id)
    FOR [month] in ([August],[September],[October],[November],[December],[January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July])
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like this:

```
SELECT Columns 
 FROM (
   SELECT columns
    FROM tbl1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT columns
    FROM tbl2
   )
PIVOT
```